# Please title the /reputation page

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, reputation-audit

This will probably affect only a handful of users, but if it is not too much trouble, is it possible to title the page?

Google Chrome's address bar does not seem to work well with plain URLs pointing to untitled pages.  This is not a problem for Firefox's awesome bar, which shows it as the first option for "re" or after a while just "r".

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the issue you are experiencing that page needs a doctype and a title to be valid HTML.. Since it's the only two things that it's missing from having it validate, and since it's 0 development effort, why not?

Comment: @Richard: Yes, sorry, I thought I upvoted you before writing the answer, but apparently I didn't. =) I did it now, though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags/5642053#5642053

Answer (score 1):

Eh?  Works fine for me:

[image]

Comment: And what did you type? "sta"... and /rep may not be in the list, depending. Try just "rep"

Comment: It shows what I've typed, but just doing `sta` has it show up.  It doesn't show up when I type `rep` or `reputation` but I don't know if Chrome is built to look inside URLs instead of just at the beginning of URLs.

Comment: @Daniel - Chrome does hunt down titles

Comment: @Richard indeed, just wanted to make sure you understood that given the current untitled nature of the page, the only way you might be able to find it is via typing "stac..." etc., but that *should* work

Comment: @Daniel - methinks you completely missed the point of the question, then

Comment: @Richard no.... you stated "Google Chrome's address bar does not seem to work well with plain URLs pointing to untitled pages." and it does, it just only works in a certain way

Comment: To be pedantic, "certain way" = match on start. "works well" = match anywhere, per Page Title matching. They are miles apart